# Very quick question about uniform distribution.

Tags: probability, random-variables, uniform-distribution

If I have a Random Variable $Y\sim U[0,60]$. 
And I'm calculating $P(Y\le z)$ for $45\le z\le60$. 
I'm having a little confusion if the answer is: $\frac{z-45}{15}$ OR $\frac{z}{60}$. 
When I solved the question I instantly wrote $\frac{z-45}{15}$, but the solution in the book says the answer is $\frac{z}{60}$. 
So it's either me having a misunderstanding of uniform distribution or the book answer is wrong. 
 
Would appreciate any feedback, thanks in advance!

Comment: It should be $\dfrac{z}{60}$. Take any value of $z$ and you can see why it is true. Say $z$ was defined as $0 \leq z \leq 60$, what would your answer be for $P(Y \leq z)$?

Comment: What you are finding is $P(45 \leq Y \leq z)$ but denominator in that case would still be $60$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The uniform probability gives every result equal weight.   So, say, the probability that a $Y\leq 20$ would just be $\frac {20} {60}=\frac 1 3$.   The same thing will work for any $z$ in the $[0,60]$ range

Comment: Thanks alot, glad I caught this problem early, I got a question if possible to make sure, say $X \sim U[45,60]$, then for $45\le z \le 60$ the answer would be $\frac{z-45}{15}$?

Comment: Correct @Pwaol .